# Can't read json array with value only on Windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, serialization

Now I have this JSON :

```
[
    "bekasi",
    "bekasi barat",
    "bekasi selatan",
    "bekasi timur",
    "bekasi utara",
    "serang bekasi"
]
```

I don't how to make the parser class. I tried the online json to c# class generator, but it can't help. So I tried this :

```
[DataContract]
public class kota
{
    [DataMember]
    public string kotanya { get; set; }

}
```

and this

```
public static kota eks; // I also tried  public static kota[] eks;

public void mulai()
    {
        string eksp = "http://www.ongkoskirim.com/api/0.2/?id=OAL66afd139a386fee6dc5a5597abd7daba&q=city&s=bek";

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(eksp), UriKind.Absolute);
    }

    void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(kota)); //and I have tried typeof(IEnumerable<kota>) 
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("sini");
            eks = (kota)ser.ReadObject(e.Result); //I also tried (kota[])ser.ReadObject(e.Result);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("sana");
            List<string> temp = new List<string>();
            temp.Add("Semua");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("list");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(eks.kotanya[i]);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

But I'm always get invalidCastException. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any extra classes as your JSON is simple array of strings:

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string[]));
var items = (string[]) ser.ReadObject(e.Result);
```

I wouldn't involve dedicated classes until your JSON gets more complex, nonetheless you can easily build list of `kota` instances:

```
var kotas = items.Select(i => new kota { kotanya = i }).ToList();
```

On a sidenote, if you plan to do more JSON de/serialization, I suggest giving a look at [JSON.NET library](http://json.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an array you want to serialize you should try this

```
 var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(kota[]));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with classes you would have to modify the `kota` class by changing the `kotanya` property to a collection of strings and the JSON string (add the name of the data member `kotanya` to describe the collection of strings and enclode the string with `{}`) before processing it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = "{\"kotanya\":[\"bekasi\",\"bekasi barat\",\"bekasi selatan\",\"bekasi timur\",\"bekasi utara\",\"serang bekasi\"]}";

    var s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(kota));
    using (var m = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        var r = s.ReadObject(m);

    }
}

[DataContract]
public class kota
{
    [DataMember]
    public string[] kotanya { get; set; }

}
```